# Reports in HP Fortify Workbench

Tags: fortify

I am using AWB version 4.10.0120 and SCA version 6.10.0120. I'm trying to generate a report in audit workbench only for critical and high issues or by comment dates. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open project report in workbench
2. Go to Reports and select the report template, i.e. Fortify Developer Workbook, OWASP top 10 2010
3. Go to results outline on right pan and in left pan you will see Refine issues in subsection, click on "Advanced" link
4. Chose the filter, Fortify Priority order: Critical &High, if you have create two filters using &operator
5. You can use the filter comments if you want to generate result based on comments contains some keywords
6. If you can apply these filter in other subsection of the report i.e. Issue count by categories, issues breakdown by analysis, executive summary.

Comment: OK. I was on the correct path but when I apply filters, I'm still getting the entire report, i.e. low's, high's and critical's which is over 6,000 pages long. I even unchecked all options in the right pan and only have results outline checked. What am I doing wrong?